# Woocommerce hide featured image on product detail page

Tags: image, woocommerce, product

When you set the featured image for a woocommerce product, it shows up as the first/main image in the gallery on the product details page. I don't want this. I simply want to hide/remove the featured image entirely from the product details page. I want the featured image to only show up in the product category page but not on a single product detail page. Any ideas on this? I seem to have a unique problem here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a simple hack with javascript:

```
$('.images').remove();
```

Or in your theme, add this to your functions.php

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_show_product_images', 20 );
```

You will most likely need to fix the CSS so it doesn't look weird without the image.

Comment: Everyone is posting this, but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Same here, I mean. It does hide the picture, but it still takes up space on my site

Answer (score 0):

The following (using jQuery), worked for me:

```
<?php

woocommerce_show_product_images();

?>
<script>

$('.slides li').first().remove();      //1
$('#carousel > div').first().remove(); //2

</script>
```

Line 1 removes the large image; line 2 removes the thumbnail.

Answer (score 0):

I used the same recommendation of this in my functions.php

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_show_product_images', 20 );
```

However since I'm using the Genesis Sample Theme I had to use the following CSS as well to get the summary to sit correctly on the left side. It's default is to float right so even though there's no more featured image the summary info still sits on the right side.

```
.summary {
    float: left !important;
}
```